# iPhone/Objective-C - Memory leaks in QuartzCore library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, quartz-graphics

I am running the Instruments Tool (Leaks) and am receiving memory leaks in the `QuartzCore` library and don't know exactly where in my code this is occurring. Usually I'm able to pin point the line where the leak is occurring, however the instrument tool isn't giving me anywhere to view this type of information.

What would be some other things I could look at in terms of diagnosing such a leak?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, try running this on the device.  Sometimes the simulator will report leaks that do not exist on the device.

Secondly, open up the stack trace  (right sidebar) and see what code of yours might be involved higher up in triggering this call, then you can think from there why that code might be leaking.

One additional bit of advice.  Instead of playing with leaks there, switch over to ObjectAlloc and use the Heapshot feature - if you know about where the leak is, use the heapshot to set a base memory measurement and every time you hit the "heapshot" button after that you'll see a kind of memory "diff" against that baseline you set.  Solving any over-retained problems might also fix your leak.

Comment: The leak is actually occurring on the device. I will try your suggestion and look at the stack trace.

Comment: Add the ObjectAlloc instrument.  You may have to delete the existing one that comes up with the Leaks chosen, if it's not marked as "record reference counts" (click on the little (i) in the instrument to view the settings).  Record again, and set the leak check time to something like two seconds (default is 10).  Then see what allocations are being done around the time the leak is recorded... also try following the arrow next to the memory address for the leak and see if you get a stack trace there.

Comment: It's actually still occurring. I thought I'd fixed it, but it didn't work. I tried removing masksToBounds and cornerRadius from a UIImageView. But it still leaks somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

If you’re only leaking 16 bytes at a time, it’s really not likely to become an issue in your app. And if the leak is occurring in a system framework, it probably isn’t your fault.

Comment: That's always comforting I guess. It seems to always be occurring at the same bit of functionality so I might debug my entire view and see what QuartzCore code I'm using...